# Probability -10 sided dice

Tags: probability

Question : we roll three fair 10 sided dice .
What’s the probability that we roll less than two times a number which greater is than 5?

What’s the probability that no die lands on 3 or 4 ?

My solution is

For Q1) I don’t get what it means by two times a number >5

would it be the P(roll< 2x where x>5) be 1 as we will be rolling less than 12,14,16,18,20

Q2) it would be 998/1000

Comment: Not sure to understand the first question. Regarding the second, show how you ended with that number. Are you really sure that basically always no die lands on 3 or 4?

Comment: I believe the first question asks "If you throw three dice, and you get the numbers $d_1,d_2,d_3$, what is the probablility that $(d_1>5\&d_2>5)\ \mathrm{or}\ (d_1>5\&d_3>5)\ \mathrm{or}\ (d_2>5\&d_3>5)$.

In general, these problems can be solved using Probability = (number of "good" configurations)/(number of possible configurations).

Comment: @nicola for Q2 I looked at all possible combinations which is 1000 and then the combination of landing (3,3,3) or (4,4,4) and there are two possible outcomes and I did 1000-2 for the numerator which gave 998

Comment: For the first question, roll the three dice.  Look at the top faces on each die.  If you record the three numbers, a favorable outcome is one in which at most one of the numbers on the top faces of the dice is greater than five.

Comment: For the second question, any outcome in which neither 3 nor 4 appears on the top face of a die is favorable.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I don’t get  your explanation for the first question

Comment: For the first question, the two types of favorable outcomes are no die shows a number greater than $5$, such as $(3, 4, 5)$ or $(4, 1, 4)$, or exactly one die shows an outcome greater than $5$, such as $(7, 3, 2)$ or $(5, 8, 5)$.

Comment: For Q1 I have understood it correctly it’s binomial Distribution and I am looking for P(X=0) + P(X=1)  and in that case I have got 1/8 +3/8 respectively which is 1/2 when you add them up

Comment: That is correct.  However, the answer you wrote for the second question is wrong.  For instance, $(2, 7, 9)$ is a favorable outcome, but you only removed cases in which all three numbers were $3$s or all $3$ numbers were $4$s.

Comment: Oh I see , that means in each roll the probability of rolling 3 or 4 is 1/5 and not rolling 3 or 4 is 4/5 so I do the binomial C(3,0)(0.2)^0(0.8)^3 should give the probability of not rolling 3 or 4

Comment: @N.F.Taussig this method is the correct method for Q2 no ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.